# Wordpress REST API JSON Authenticate

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and Jetpack on a self hosted WP site and I would like to use the Wordpress REST API to create posts from a different application also on the web using just HTML & JQuery.

I can get the unauthenticated data but when I try and add a new post it requires an access token.

I have written the following,

```
        wpAuth.bind('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    'client_id': 'client id',
                    'client_secret': 'secret token',
                    'grant_type': 'password',
                    'username': 'wp.comuser',
                    'password': 'a password',
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function( response ) {
                    console.log( response ); // server response
                }
            });             

        });
```

But I get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token. Origin
>   http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can someone help me understand what is the problem, I have the `Javascript Origins` setup at developer.wordpress.com for my app.

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)? You should check header response.

Comment: Yeah checked that out but I think this issue I am facing is at the Wordpress API end?

Comment: Im pretty sure that their oauth2 api aint set up to handle cross browser calls due to security standard. If you try this with a CURL call in PHP im sure it will be alright.

Comment: Was trying to avoid PHP in this case as the source application is running on a windows server that I have no control over. But thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The response header from their API is: x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-hacker:If you're reading this, you should visit automattic.com/jobs and apply to join the fun, mention this header.
x-nananana:Batcache